# Get request Header name and value

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, kotlin, request

I have the endpoint below where I get as a parameter an Authorization Header.

I need to find out its name but I cant figure out how to obtain that information. The actual string I get is something like below:

"Basic FJsdfFOisr8kZXKasrosLFcw2jf9fjsew9ltRlFEbsfeFA9d3jl1QU02Ulcxj28ADBlsfr="

```
@PostMapping(Endpoints.DEPOSITS.WITHDRAWALS)
fun withdrawals(@RequestBody withdrawalsData: WithdrawalData, @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)  authHeader : String): String? {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header name here, would be `HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION`.
Have a look at `org.springframework.http`